# Are there predefined Military awards in d20?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, d20-system, d20-modern

I would like to run a military campaign starting in medieval times (D&D). The only military award or decoration that I know of in the d20 system (off the top of my head) is the [Medal of Steadfast Honor](http://rpgzone.lefora.com/topic/15727541/Medal-of-Steadfast-Honor-Magic-Item-Compendium) from the Magic Item Compendium. Are there any other decorations in print somewhere?

I would like to have awards that could be issued and passed down through the generations.

---

The premise is to roleplay our way through the centuries, and will be roleplaying characters that are ancestors/descendents of the previous.

- 1st Campaign: Dungeons and Dragons (Crusades).
- 2nd Campaign: Dungeons and Dragons (Revolutionary War & Civil War).
- 3rd Campaign: d20 Modern (WWI & WWII).
- 4th Campaign: d20 Modern (Iraq & Afghanistan).
- 5th Campaign: d20 Modern (Future Sci/Fi - Aliens & Predator d20).

---

If a medal can provide a mechanical benefit, all the better! If not, then at least proper nomenclature of said awards. To simplify it further, keep it as English as possible (i.e. England during the crusades, United States for later conflicts), but as in game as possible. I have access to US Army regulations (in fact copies are on my bookshelf) for awards and decorations - that is modern times - and also not fantasy.

Comment: @Thunderforge thank you Thunderforge, I addressed that concern in an edit.

Comment: If you do this, beware of players trying to guarantee their characters' survival by claiming they don't yet have offspring.

Comment: A quick Google didn't turn up any other D&D3.5e magical medals. Nonmagical ones would vary by campaign setting, if they are defined anywhere. If you're having it as (semi-)historical, perhaps you should look at historical military awards?

Comment: @Adeptus As prior Army, and a veteran of foreign war, I would have no trouble at all for nomenclature of awards and decorations for modern. I was more worried about the medievil part. I am a history buff but not necessarily a military history buff. I was also hoping for more defined in game military items, such as the aforementioned Medal of Steadfast Honor.

Comment: If you are just looking for nomenclature, maybe History.SE would be better for this question as there are more experts over there who would know about this sort of thing. Of course if you want mechanical benefits, that is something we could help with.

Comment: @Thunderforge I want to use as much fantasy/in-game awards as possible before I start from the drawing board and use real ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heroes of Battle has a system of rank and awards (along with benefits) that may suit your purposes.  Additionally, the rules for Organizations may give you another option for 'keeping score' of PC accomplishments and incrementing rewards.

Page 89 of Heroes of Battle:

> **Decorations**
>
> Every army has a different system of decorations, from the simple (barbarian hordes who wear body parts of the foes they slay) to the complex (national armies with multiple medals, each with one of several ribbon colors for specific occasions). When you design an army, one of the features you can construct is a system of decorations that the army gives to soldiers who show excellence of one kind or another on the battlefield.
>
> **Chivalric Army Decorations**
>
> [image: Table 4-8: Sample Decorations]